# Int Identity Column with Descriminator

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with a column that should auto-increment, however it should increment over another descriminator column

for example:

| Id | Filenumber | Descriminator | More Columns... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2AA15D5E-F158-45AE-902C-CD49644846BC | 1 | A |  |
| FE6B95EE-DFF4-48D4-9BD7-7DB4187A2D6D | 2 | A |  |
| 2A132492-447A-485D-A546-2FB9158AE71B | 1 | B |  |

So if I would enter another entry with Descriminator "A" I would get Filenumber 3. But by adding an entry with "B", i would get 2, because it's the 2nd "B" Row.

The only way I know is a Update-Trigger but is there an easier solution or if it's the only way, is it reliable with heavy traffic (load-balanced system with many users)?

Comment: If you only have a few "Descriminator"s you could use a few `SEQUENCE`s; one for each different value.

Comment: The Descriminators unfortunatly are not static

Comment: Define your Filenumber in a *view* and query the view.

Comment: @Stu by adding a timestamp and order partition by and rownumber?

Comment: Not a `timestamp`, @FlorianSchmidinger , that's a deprecated synonym for `rowversion`, but an always ascending value of some kind (either an `IDENTITY` or date and time value) would work.

Comment: lol sorry, im not up to date with database lingo =)

Comment: well, that's all to sketchy for me and the extra mile with that view i'd have to maintain, for this table is changing way to often.

Comment: *"for this table is changing way to often."* As in the definition is changing too often? That sounds like a problem if so, if I am honest. The table's definition can change, yes, but it shouldn't be changing often.

Comment: If Descriminator was static you could use an AFTER INSERT trigger to calculate it for new records. But since it can change, you should probably leave the calculation to the reporting. Easy with the ROW_NUMBER or DENSE_RANK functions.

Comment: *but it shouldn't be changing often*  - agreed, unfortunatly not in my responsibility

Comment: A table schema changing too often could be a hint that the schema is not normalized. E.g. You could move properties that are subject to schema changes to two new tables. A table `property` uniquely identifying each property and a join table `main_property` having a `main_id`, `property_id` and a `value` column for that property.

Comment: *"nfortunatly not in my responsibility"* Yet appears it is if you need to implement some kind of solution for the above.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes *schema is not normalized* - far away from it agreed, legacy databases seldom are =(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The only way I know is a Update-Trigger but is there an easier solution or if it's the only way, is it reliable with heavy traffic (load-balanced system with many users)?

There's not really any way to do this that doesn't sacrifice scalability.

> UpdateTrigger With Try Catch in combination with an uniqueindex over these columns maybe?

Yes it's possible, but I wouldn't recommend it.  You'll end up with blocking, and perhaps deadlocking so it will require careful coding, index design and testing. And best-case your DML will be much more expensive than it could be since it has to query all the other rows in the same discriminator, and there's simply no way for sessions to concurrently run DML within the same discriminator.

If you did want to go down this road, I would maintain a seperate table  with Discriminator as the PK, and LastFileNumber.  That way you don't have to scan over lots of rows to figure out the next FileNumber.

So something like:

```
create table Discriminator(Discriminator varchar(10) not null primary key, LastFileNumber int)
```

And then in your trigger or stored procedure for each row:

```
set nocount on
declare @discriminator varchar(10) = 'a';
declare @fn int
declare @fnt table(fn int)

merge discriminator with (updlock, holdlock)  as t 
using (select 1 fn) as s
on t.Discriminator = @discriminator
when matched then update set t.LastFileNumber = t.LastFileNumber + 1
when not matched then insert (Discriminator,LastFileNumber) values (@discriminator,1)
output inserted.LastFileNumber
into @fnt;

set @fn = (select fn from @fnt)
```

But the easiest and best performing solution is to abandon the "requirement" that the FileNumbers are sequential within each "discriminator" and simply use a SEQUENCE or IDENTITY to generate them.  so you get

| Id | Filenumber | Descriminator | More Columns... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2AA15D5E-F158-45AE-902C-CD49644846BC | 1 | A |  |
| FE6B95EE-DFF4-48D4-9BD7-7DB4187A2D6D | 2 | A |  |
| 2A132492-447A-485D-A546-2FB9158AE71B | 3 | B |  |

and if you want to *display* the ordinal within each discriminator you can query it like

```
select
    Id,
    row_number() over (partition by Discriminator order by FileNumber) FileOrdinal,
    Discriminator
from T
```

Comment: UpdateTrigger With Try Catch in combination with an uniqueindex over these columns maybe?

Comment: Gonna try that thanks. Just another idea: ... if i'd have this simple identity column, the calculation of the partition rownumbers by would be deterministic right? ... would then a persisted computed column do the trick?

Comment: No.  Because you could delete a row.

Comment: thats one thing we dont do... unless the server does this internally?

Comment: But you could, so the computed column would be non-deterministic.  If you want to compute a value only on insert you need a trigger.

Answer (score 2):

@Larnu has already alluded to this in the comments, but I thought it was worth showing you how simple this kind of thing can be, and with the right indexes calculating the descriminator should be happily swift enough!

In short, your table design can be changed to have a compound, clustered primary key on the `file_number` and an additional, incrementing field such as a `revision_date`.

```sql
CREATE TABLE your_table (
   file_number   int      NOT NULL
 , revision_date datetime NOT NULL CONSTRAINT df_your_table_revision_date (getutcdate())
 , CONSTRAINT pk_your_table PRIMARY KEY (file_number, revision_date)
);
```

You can then create a view on top of your table, which can be used for all your data access needs for simplicity:

```sql
CREATE VIEW your_data_access_view
  AS
SELECT filenumber
     , revision_date
     , Row_Number() OVER (PARTITION BY filenumber ORDER BY revision_date) AS descriminator
FROM   your_table
;
```

To show it in action:

```sql
INSERT INTO your_table (file_number) VALUES (1);
WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:01';
INSERT INTO your_table (file_number) VALUES (2);
WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:01';
INSERT INTO your_table (file_number) VALUES (1);

SELECT filenumber
     , revision_date
     , descriminator
FROM   your_data_access_view
ORDER
    BY filenumber
     , descriminator
;
```